# React Native: How can I add user to Android account manager?

Tags: android, react-native, accountmanager

I am working on a mobile application using React Native.

What I want to do is to add user data as an account to Android account manager for further access.

[image]

It helps me to remember user token for next time user opens the application.

I know there is another way to remember user using AsyncStorage. But I need to add account in account manager.
I did so many research on this and found [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-account-manager) but it doesn't help me because it is overriding some deprecated methods.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @mehghad hadidi did you manager to figure a solution out ?

Comment: @julestruong No, not yet